# How to create request with OR for different fields in AIF Soap UI

Tags: soap, microsoft-dynamics, axapta, aif

I have webservice AIF from Dynamics AX 2012 which return information from CustTable. How can I write request that return me information about Customers with AccountNum "1111" OR Blocked "NO".
How can I write query with OR condition?
If I write something like this I receive AND condition.

```
<quer:QueryCriteria>
    <quer:CriteriaElement>
        <quer:DataSourceName>CustTable</quer:DataSourceName>
        <quer:FieldName>AccountNum</quer:FieldName>
        <quer:Operator>Equal</quer:Operator>
        <quer:Value1>1111</quer:Value1>   
        <quer:Value2></quer:Value2>
    </quer:CriteriaElement>
    <quer:CriteriaElement>
        <quer:DataSourceName>CustTable</quer:DataSourceName>
        <quer:FieldName>Blocked</quer:FieldName>
        <quer:Operator>Equal</quer:Operator>
        <quer:Value1>no</quer:Value1>   
        <quer:Value2></quer:Value2>
    </quer:CriteriaElement>
</quer:QueryCriteria>
```

Comment: Documentation says that  system always uses Boolean OR logic to connect all the <CriteriaElement> tags. This means that the record information returned in the outbound message comes from records that satisfy any one of the following <CriteriaElement> conditions.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/query-criteria-overview

Comment: @AliaksandrMaksimau, consider converting to an answer.

Comment: Yes @AliaksandrMaksimau documentation says it, but it is not true. Between <CriteriaElement> in my example is AND not OR.